# Inequality for the global dimension

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional  algebra with finite global dimension g and Loewy length l and dimension of the Jacobson radical being r.
Do we have $g \leq r-(l-2)$ ?

$g \leq r$ was proven in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-108-03/S0002-9939-1990-1031675-8/S0002-9939-1990-1031675-8.pdf for monomial algebras.

Comment: This is an interesting, but hard, problem.  To add some context, Schofield (Bull. London Math. Soc. 17 (1985), no. 4, 393-394) has shown that there is a function $f$ such that $g \leq f(\dim A)$.  But I do not even know if $g \leq \dim A$ is true in general.